# Manga about journey of immortal girl who passes on her consciousness to each child she has

Tags: story-identification, manga, immortality

The girl passes on her consciousness to the child that she gives birth to and thus she is immortal. Her history dates from ancient times and there is one exception where she gives birth to twins (in modern day Japan) and thus effectively becomes the boy's sister and mother at the same time. She smokes and monologes quite a bit.

Her brother makes his appearance only few times. Usually when her consciousness is transferred her old body retains only basic mental prowess and becomes a husk of its previous person. Other important characters in the story that I remember would be her husband in one of her lifetimes.

It was mostly black and white and the story genre is slice of life. I want to check if it has been updated/axed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: It was mostly black and white. I dont quite remember the names of any characters

Comment: How does the immortality and consciousness work in relation to the story? Is this entirely in the back story, or does the protagonist change bodies every few chapters/volumes? And the twins - is this a historical detail, or is it the start of the story and the manga shows this immortal girl's relationship to herself and her twin brother?

Comment: The story genre is slice of life. Her brother makes his appearance only few times. Usually when her consciousness is transferred her old body retains only basic mental prowess and becomes a husk of its previous person. Other important characters in the story that I remember would be her husband in one of her lifetime. The twins are born in modern day japan

Comment: Slice of the life of a serial killer...

Comment: Do you remember what year you read this in, and about how many chapters there were at the time?

Comment: I read it around 5 years ago. It had around 20 chapters then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like [*Omoide Emanon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanon_(manga)) ("Memories of Emanon") by Kenji Tsuruta.

From Wikipedia's synopsis:

> The series follows the travels of Emanon (エマノン) ("No Name" backwards), a mysterious young woman who possesses a three-billion-year-old memory, dating back to the creation of life. Emanon has been reborn countless times, retaining all the memories and experiences from all her past lives. She wanders around the world with no clear destination in mind, and will continue to do so again and again many times in the future.

Comment: Yes that's it. Thanks a ton !

Comment: Omoide Emanon ("Memories of Emanon") is a prequel to Sasurai Emanon ("Wandering Emanon")